# Powershell script to run 4 instances of same program [complete newbie]

Tags: powershell

!Hi there,

Getting my hands on Powershell script, I have a simple (but yet to work) script whose purpose is to run 4 instances of same program (which also happens to be a video game - long story short the game policy, terms and conditions allows multi-account but the laucher is shitty and doesn't work well when launching multiple instances of said game). Anyway...

First things first, for some reasons, I can't seem to be able to run 4 instances of that .exe in particular without "-Verb RunAs". If I were to remove this part of the script then I only get one instance to run and the other 3 never launch. Tried with notepad.exe and calc.exe, works perfectly fine but this one .exe, nope... !

Now, since I'm lazy af and have some time to waste, I really don't want to have to use my mouse and click "Yes" on the User Account Control (UAC) in between every instance that launches, then I was thinking of improving the script because there's probably a way around it. First I tried disabling the UAC on line 1 with a cmdlet, have the rest of the script run, then enabling again UAC on last line, I got the same result as if I were to delete "-Verb RunAs", only one instance shows up.

So here's the solution I came up with at last : Having the script wait for the UAC to be there, then send the keys "left" then "enter" so it goes on "Yes" then confirms the UAC and that in between each instances.

And here is how I coded that which is probably terrible and very wrong. However in order to test it out I'm missing the UAC process name's to replace the ***. I've been trying to look for it but when the UAC is there nothing shows anymore on screen but its window so I don't have access to Task Manager or anything else and I couldn't find it by myself.

```js
Start-process "C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Local\Ankama\zaap\dofus\Dofus.exe" -Verb RunAs
Wait-process -Name *** -Timeout 2
.SendKeys ({LEFT})({ENTER})
Start-process "C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Local\Ankama\zaap\dofus\Dofus.exe" -Verb RunAs
Wait-process -Name *** -Timeout 2
.SendKeys ({LEFT})({ENTER})
Start-process "C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Local\Ankama\zaap\dofus\Dofus.exe" -Verb RunAs
Wait-process -Name *** -Timeout 2
.SendKeys ({LEFT})({ENTER})
Start-process "C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Local\Ankama\zaap\dofus\Dofus.exe" -Verb RunAs
Wait-process -Name *** -Timeout 2
.SendKeys ({LEFT})({ENTER})
```

The script won't probably work anyway, I feel like I'm missing a lot (like a lot) of lines still but yeah... Sorry for the long post. Help a newbie ! :|

> Edit 1 : Found a way to shorten the script, but it still won't launch
> all 4 instances unless I have "RunAs" at the end. Still need to either
> have the UCA in between launches answered Yes to itself or find a way
> to successfully run the 4 instances without having to "RunAs":

```js
1..4 | ForEach-Object { Start-process -FilePath   "C:\Users\Benjamin\AppData\Local\Ankama\zaap\dofus\Dofus.exe" -Verb RunAs }
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid dealing with UAC 4 times instead of 1? Or are you trying to avoid UAC altogether?

Comment: Thanks for your reply zdan. Well first I tried dealing with UAC once by disabling it, have the 4 instances of my .exe launch then reenabling UAC but as I said by doing so I only get one instance to launch (IDK why). It seems that in order to have all my 4 instances launch I need to have the UAC "proc" in between each instance launch. That's weird I know but that's the only way I found to have all my 4 instances to launch. So I'm trying to have my script wait for, then answer yes to each UAC that comes up in between each instance launch, until every instances is launched basicly.

Comment: BTW, there's probably a way to have all my 4 instances launch without having to "RunAs" that would be optimal, though I don't know what's causing the command only being able to launch 1 instance without the "RunAs" condition...